# Updating mutable state in Jetpack Compose depending on function parameters

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This question is about updating and merging states in Jetpack Compose.

There is a `ViewModel` which provides a list of items with ids, labels and some extra payload.

I want to create a list with expandable items. So I need to store item expanded status somewhere. I can surely hoist it to `ViewModel` level, but it is more a view state, like animation, and it is not needed at upper levels.

[image: Schema]

Without state hoisting I need to merge states to remove not existing items from expanded set. It can be done like this.

```
@Composable
private fun List(
    items: List<String>
) {
    val expandedState = remember { mutableStateMapOf<String, Unit>() }
    expandedState.keys.retainAll(items) //keep only existing items
    ListStateless(
        onExpand = { id -> expandedState[id] = Unit },
        onCollapse = { id -> expandedState.remove(id) },
        items = items,
        expandedState = expandedState.keys
    )
}

@Composable
private fun ListStateless(
    onExpand: (id: String) -> Unit,
    onCollapse: (id: String) -> Unit,
    items: List<String>,
    expandedItems: Set<String>
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(
            count = items.size,
            key = { index -> "Item:${items[index]}" }
        ) { index ->
            val item = items[index]
            val isExpanded = expandedItems.contains(item)
            Text(
                text = "$item $isExpanded",
                modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                    if (!isExpanded) {
                        onExpand(item)
                    } else {
                        onCollapse(item)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

But does it provide any negative impact on performance? Do I need to make this mutation in side effect? Maybe there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to make a list of items in the `ViewModel`.

Let's say of this type:

```kotlin
data class Item(
    val value: String,
    val isExpanded: Boolean
)
```

Then in the ViewModel you would have something like:

```kotlin
private val _items = mutableStateOf<List<Item>>(emptyList())
val items: State<List<Item>> by lazy { 
    _items.value = getItemsFromSomewhere()
    _items
}

fun onExpandClick(item: Item) {
    _items.value = _items.value.map {
        if (it == item) {
            it.copy(isExpanded = true)
        } else it
    }
}

fun onCollapseClick(item: Item) {
    _items.value = _items.value.map {
        if (it == item) {
            it.copy(isExpanded = false)
        } else it
    }
}
```

If you do this the Composable is only in charge of displaying the state and the ViewModel is in charge of keeping and updating it.

In this example I used
`androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState` and
`androidx.compose.runtime.State` in the ViewModel,
but you could also do the same with
`kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow` and `kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow` or something else
if you prefer.